# Need assistance with some game code (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

The problem is a tiny bit complicated which is why the title is a bit vague.

So I'm making a top-down RPG in JavaFX and need a slight bit of advice. My class that is the main game window is a StackPane and adds in all the graphics (ImageView) through getChildren().add(imageviewnode). As most of you should know JavaFX containers use an ObservableList<> for their container (ie. getChildren() returns an ObservableList<>). My problem is with the ordering of this list.

So to give you an idea there is a underlayment layer (ImageView) with z value of 0, a water layer with z value of 1, a ground layer with z value of 2, all the characters that move around the map with z values between 100-199, a parallax layer (map that's displayed above the characters) with z value of 200, and a light layer for candle lights and stuff with z value of 300.

Take the following image as an example.
[image]

So, the problem I'm having with this is the z ordering in getChildren(). At first I thought maybe adding each image at their particular z value would work such as: getChildren().add(200, parallax), but this throws an error because the ObservableList size is out of bounds. Another problem I'm having with this is all the characters z placing. If I have the player on the map and a random NPC if the player is in front of the NPC (greater Y value) the player must be on top as to appear in front of that NPC. If the player walks behind the NPC (smaller Y value) the player needs to be in back of that NPC. toFront() and toBack() don't work because if I say toFront() on the player it puts him on top of everything. I need a way to modify the indexes of each individual imageview in the ObservableList. Am I going about this in all the wrong way? If so what would be a better way? If I'm going about it in the right way but not thinking about the proper technique please let me know.

Thanks, Phil.

Comment: Every child node in the layout can have a property z-index. While adding a new child to this layout, you can simply loop the child list and compare the new z-index to their z-index values, and put new child in appropriate place/order of the layout.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but this isn't the issue. The issue is when all the nodes are already in the layout and I need to move one of them to a different z value.